# Using MVC 4 areas at custom path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm trying to use areas at a custom path, and I'm having issues. I've been googeling a bunch, but havent found a solution.

My project is a EPiServer CMS project (which shouldn't have any effect I think, just wanna mention it, in case it does)

My structure is

- Root

  - CompanyName

    - Areas

      - Commerce

        - Controllers
        - Models
        - Views
      - Cms

        - Controllers

          - HomePageController
        - Models
        - Views

          - HomePage

            - Index.cshtml

So I have a layer more to the tree then 'normal' which is the 'CompanyName'

I have this in global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AreaTemplateViewEngineDynamic());
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    ...
}
```

I have a Custom RazorEngine (Could have just added more paths to the default, but have this solution as of now)

```
public class AreaTemplateViewEngineDynamic : RazorViewEngine
{
    public AreaTemplateViewEngineDynamic()
    {
        this.PartialViewLocationFormats = this.ViewLocationFormats = this.MasterLocationFormats =
                new string[]
                {
                    "~/CompanyName/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/CompanyName/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
                };

        this.AreaMasterLocationFormats = this.AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = this.AreaViewLocationFormats =
                new string[]
                {
                    "~/CompanyName/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/CompanyName/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
                };
    }
}
```

Adding this area registration

```
public class CmsAreaRegistration: AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "Commerce"; }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Cms_default",
            "Cms/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Root.CompanyName.Areas.Cms.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

When I try to load the page, it seems it doesnt look at the Area paths, only the non-area paths.

The view 'index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:

- ~/Views/HomePage/index.aspx
- ~/Views/HomePage/index.ascx
- ~/Views/Shared/index.aspx
- ~/Views/Shared/index.ascx
- ~/Views/HomePage/index.cshtml
- ~/Views/HomePage/index.vbhtml
- ~/Views/Shared/index.cshtml
- ~/Views/Shared/index.vbhtml
- ~/CompanyName/Views/HomePage/index.cshtml
- ~/CompanyName/Views/Shared/index.cshtml

The path I want it to find is

- ~/CompanyName/Areas/Cms/Views/HomePage/index.cshtml

Also if I had to use

```
@{Html.RenderAction("MiniCart", "Cart", new { area = "Commerce"} );}
```

I would expect it to finde

- ~/CompanyName/Areas/Commerce/Views/Cart/MiniCart.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my own RazorViewEngine, where I added some custom codes to finding paths.
Could just use the URL, because the URL was controlled by the CMS, so the URL  didnt represent the MVC path.

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting the location for the AreaMasterLocation when you should also set the following locations:

- AreaPartialViewLocationFormats
- AreaViewLocationFormats

Find the following class in the object browser: VirtualPathProviderViewEngine for more properties and methods.